# Query for master records that have matching detail records

Tags: sql, t-sql

Currently I'm having the following table structure.

Master table **Documents**:

| ID | Filename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | document1.pdf |
| 2 | document2.pdf |
| 3 | document3.pdf |

Detail table **Keywords**:

| ID | DocumentID | Keyword |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | KeywordA |
| 2 | 1 | KeywordB |
| 3 | 1 | KeywordC |
| 4 | 2 | KeywordB |
| 5 | 3 | KeywordA |
| 6 | 3 | KeywordD |

Code to create this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Documents (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Filename nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Keywords (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DocumentID int NOT NULL,
    Keyword nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Documents(Filename) VALUES 
  ('document1.pdf'), ('document2.pdf'), ('document3.pdf');

INSERT INTO Keywords(DocumentID, Keyword) VALUES 
  (1, 'KeywordA'),
  (1, 'KeywordB'),
  (1, 'KeywordC'),
  (2, 'KeywordB'),
  (3, 'KeywordA'),
  (3, 'KeywordD');
```

[SQL Fiddle for this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/918615/1).

#### Finding with one keyword

I'm looking for a way to get all documents matching a certain keyword.

This could be e.g. written with the following T-SQL query:

```sql
SELECT Documents.* 
FROM Documents 
WHERE Documents.ID IN
(
  SELECT Keywords.DocumentID 
  FROM Keywords 
  WHERE Keywords.Keyword = 'KeywordA'
)
```

This works successfully.

#### Finding with multiple keywords

What I'm currently stuck with is when I want to find all documents that match multiple keyword, combined with logical AND.

E.g. find a document that has three detail records with keyword A, B and C.

I think the following might work, but I don't know whether this performant or elegant at all:

```sql
SELECT Documents.* 
FROM Documents 
WHERE Documents.ID IN
(
  SELECT Keywords.DocumentID 
  FROM Keywords
  WHERE 
    Keywords.Keyword = 'KeywordA' OR 
    Keywords.Keyword = 'KeywordB' 
  GROUP BY Keywords.DocumentID HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
)
```

[SQL Fiddle for that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/918615/3).

#### My question

How to write a (performant) SQL query to find all documents that have multiple keywords associated.

If it is easier, a solution with a constant number of keywords (e.g. 3) would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following query can help you

```
SELECT D.ID
FROM Documents D
JOIN Keywords K ON K.DocumentID = D.ID
WHERE K.Keyword IN ('KeywordA', 'KeywordB', 'KeywordC')  
GROUP BY D.ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT K.Keyword) = 3
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=67b5b904b57b39310ee605c17b18d02c)

Answer (score 1):

The technique you are trying to do is called [**Relational Division With Remainder**](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), in other words: find all groups which contain a particular set of rows.

**Your current query is one of the standard ways of doing this, there are others.**

If you had the keywords in a table variable or TVP, ...

```sql
DECLARE @keywords AS TABLE (Keyword varchar(50));
INSERT @keywords VALUES
('KeywordA'), ('KeywordB'), ('KeywordC');
```

... you could make it much neater with the following:

```sql
SELECT d.* 
FROM Documents d
WHERE d.ID IN
(
  SELECT k.DocumentID 
  FROM Keywords k
  JOIN @keywords kt ON kt.Keyword = k.Keyword
  GROUP BY k.DocumentID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @keywords)
);
```

Another option:

```sql
SELECT d.* 
FROM Documents d 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM @keywords kt
  LEFT JOIN Keywords k ON kt.Keyword = k.Keyword
      AND k.DocumentID = d.ID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(k.keywords) -- there are no missing matches
);
```

And another, slightly confusing one:

```sql
SELECT d.* 
FROM Documents d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @keywords kt
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM Keywords k
        WHERE k.Keyword = kt.Keyword
        AND K.DocumentID = d.ID
    )
);
-- For each document, there are no keywords for which there is no match
```