# Rewriting an SQL statement as a LINQ query results in runtime error

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

As a follow-up to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67466577/107625) I have got this SQL:

```sql
SELECT Documents.* 
FROM Documents 
WHERE Documents.ID IN
(
  SELECT Keywords.DocumentID 
  FROM Keywords
  WHERE 
    Keywords.Keyword = 'KeywordA' OR 
    Keywords.Keyword = 'KeywordB' 
  GROUP BY Keywords.DocumentID 
  HAVING COUNT(Keywords.Keyword) = 2 
)
```

I did use [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) to convert the query to C# to use with Entity Framework Core 5:

```cs
from Document in db.Document
where
    (from Keyword in db.Keyword
    where
      Keyword.Value == "KeywordA" ||
      Keyword.Value == "KeywordB"
    group Keyword by new {
      Keyword.DocumentId
    } into g
    where g.Count(p => p.Value != null) == 2
    select new {
      g.Key.DocumentId
    }).Contains(new { DocumentId = Document.DocumentId })
select Document
```

This compiles successfully, but upon running the query, I get an error:

> The LINQ expression '`<see below>`' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

The formatted LINQ expression from the above error message reads:

```cs
DbSet<Keyword>()
    .Where(k => k.Value == "KeywordA" || k.Value == "KeywordB")
    .GroupBy(
        keySelector: k => new { DocumentId = k.DocumentId }, 
        elementSelector: k => k)
    .Where(e => e
        .Count(p => p.Value != null) == 2)
    .Select(e => new { DocumentId = e.Key.DocumentId })
    .Any(p => p == new { DocumentId = EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: Document
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
        IsNullable: False
    .DocumentId })
```

I really do not understand what's wrong here. I could only imagine that Linqer is too old to generate valid C# code for use in EF Core 5.

#### My question

Could someone give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong here and how to resolve the issue? (I.e. how to rewrite the C# query)

Comment: What happens if, instead of `select new {g.Key.DocumentId}).Contains(...)` you try `select 1).Any()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core query translation still doesn't support many LINQ constructs, and all that without documentation of what exactly is/is not supported really puts us on the trial-and-error path, thus it's not surprising that external tools cannot produce a "proper" translation.

In this particular case the problem is `Contains` call with complex argument (event though it is a class with single member). Because they support only `Contains` with primitive argument.

So the minimal change needed to make this work is to replace

```
select new
{
    g.Key.DocumentId
}).Contains(new { DocumentId = Document.DocumentId })
```

with

```
select g.Key.DocumentId).Contains(Document.DocumentId)
```

Comment: Thanks, Ivan, this seems to work. I now get an error `'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'` at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull() when materializing the query (e.g. calling `.ToList()` on the result). Since I thought I already check for `null` I'm not sure on why this occurs now.

Comment: Seems that [your suggestion there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889874/107625) applies here, too.

Comment: Yeah, that's a separate issue. You should be getting it even if you do simply `db.Document.ToList()`. You have to find which `Document` property is marked/using non nullable type and has `null` value in the database.

Comment: Actually it was an `int` that should have been an `int?` and also a `DateTime` that should have been an `DateTime?`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58839243/107625).

Comment: `string` marked as `[Required]` or `int?` mapped to `int` doesn't matter - EF does not expect `null` coming from database. And the class type or atribute or fluent config must be corrected to reflect the database table column nullability.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `.Contains(new { DocumentId = Document.DocumentId })` part is your problem. It's having trouble translating it into an expression because **Document** hasn't been evaluated at that point.

If you have the FK setup, you could refactor it this way:

```
from d in db.Documents
where d.Keywords
       .Where(k => (new[] { "keyword A", "keyword B" }).Contains(k.Keyword))
       .Count() == 2
select d
```

Comment: Are you sure this compiles (here in my program, it doesn't)? Seems that in `select k.DocumentId` the `k` is unknown.

Comment: edited the selected statement. you can select `d`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result =
    from Document in db.Document
    where
        (from Keyword in db.Keyword
         where
       Keyword.Value == "KeywordA" ||
       Keyword.Value == "KeywordB"
         group Keyword by Keyword.DocumentId
          into g
         where g.Count(p => p.Value != null) == 2
         select g.Key).Any(d => d == Document.DocumentId)
    select Document;
```

Answer (score 1):

If having 2 separate queries, 1 for the keywords and 1 for the documents, is not an issue, this should work too:

```cs
var matchedDocumentIds = db.Keywords
    .Where(keyword => keyword.Keyword == "KeywordA" || keyword.Keyword == "KeywordB")
    .GroupBy(keyword => keyword.DocumentID)
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 2)
    .Select(grp => grp.Key);

var filteredDocs = db.Documents.Where(doc => matchedDocumentIds.Any(matchedDocId => matchedDocId == doc.ID));
```

This assumes there is a foreign key in place between the 2 tables.